# How do I handle @available() for protocol function-overrides?

Tags: ios, swift3

Scenario: 
I'm trying to filter out iOS 10 code via 
`@available()` &  
`if #available()`.

I using **@available()** for the higher-scope: **classes** & **extensions**.  
But I'm getting compiler errors for the **override functions**:

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `UIPresentationController` headers, the  `presentationTransitionWillBegin` is available as of iOS 8, so the compiler is confused by your declaration that your override is available as of 10, whereas the method it's overriding is as of 8.0.

Comment: Looks like my UIViewController was peppered with iOS8+ and iOS10+ codes.   The culling of 'availabilities' did the trick.

Comment: I had clicked the 'up-arrow' instead.  Sorry... yes you did answer my questions. BTW: adding the compiler directives also opened up the iOS versions within my Schema list.... pleasant surprise.